# absolute value of column in list of dataframes

Tags: r

I have a pulled out the following list element:

```
head(roc.split[[17]][3])

      SCORE
23514   0.0
22298  0.01
22314  0.01
22429  0.01
22240 -0.02
22592 -0.04
```

where I want to take the absolute value of SCORE - just for this one element only. But when I do the following:

```
abs(roc.split[[17]][3])
```

> Error in Math.data.frame(roc.split[[17]][3]) : 
>         non-numeric variable in data frame: SCORE

It seems this is because SCORE is classed as a character:

```
summary(roc.split[[17]][3])
    SCORE          
 Length:668        
 Class :character  
 Mode  :character
```

but yet the following won't work either:

```
abs(as.numeric(roc.split[[17]][3]))
```

> Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double

so I guess my question would be - how do I take the absolute value of the column SCORE in this particular list element?

Thanks.

'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second error occurs because you are trying to convert a whole data frame to numeric.

```
#Dummy Data
dput(d1)
structure(list(v1 = c("1", "2", "-4", "-5", "8")), .Names = "v1", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")

abs(d1)
```

> Error in Math.data.frame(d1) : non-numeric variable in data frame: v1

```
as.numeric(d1)
```

> Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

To get this to work you can either call it on the vector `SCORE` (in this case `v1`), or use `transform` to convert it to numeric, i.e.

```
abs(as.numeric(d1$v1))
#[1] 1 2 4 5 8

abs(transform(d1, v1 = as.numeric(v1)))
#  v1
#1  1
#2  2
#3  4
#4  5
#5  8
```

Note: The correct way to convert a data frame to numeric (from character) would be,

```
d1[] <- lapply(d1, as.numeric)
```

If you have a list to convert to numeric then,

```
l1 <- list(d1, d1, d1)
l1 <- lapply(l1, function(i){i[] <- lapply(i, as.numeric); i})

#and to get the absolut values of all data frames in l1 then simply,
l1 <- lapply(l1, abs)

#Or All in one go,
l1 <- lapply(l1, function(i) {i[] <- lapply(i, as.numeric); abs(i)})
```

Comment: Hi Sotos - I think the fact I am dealing with a list of dataframes, rather than just a dataframe is making it complicated. For example I have tried `lapply(roc.split, as.numeric)` but get `Error in lapply(roc.split, as.numeric) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'`

Comment: however `lapply(roc.split[[17]][3], as.numeric)` does work but then I get: `> abs(lapply(roc.split[[17]][3], as.numeric))
Error in abs(lapply(roc.split[[17]][3], as.numeric)) : 
  non-numeric argument to mathematical function`

Comment: Because you are trying to convert a list to data frame (same as before but you upgraded from vector to dataframe, you now went to dataframe to list :)). I updated my answer

Comment: Hi Sotos - thanks for updating have now accepted this answer. cheers!